# Count all checkboxes that are checked in the entire DOM even when they are not displayed with DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a table that contains a list of cities. Every row has a checkbox with `city` class.

Although all cities are present in the source code of the page the table show only ten city at time (because I want it to do so). In the bottom of the table there is a button that shows the next cities.

I want to know how many checkboxes are checked.

So, I tried `$('.city').length`, but this function counts only the checkboxes present in the table at that moment, and not the checkboxes that are effectively present in the DOM. (For example: in the DOM there are 30 cities present, the table shows only 10 cities at time. The function above returns 10.)

How can I count all checkboxes that are checked?

**UPDATE**:

Using DataTable, I solved with:

var nodes = $('#table').DataTable().rows().nodes();

With it I get all rows of table.

Comment: Add HTML code or create demo on jsfiddle

Comment: Could you post an example of your code as `$('.city')` should return all checkboxes, no matter whether they are hidden or not. We need to know whether you elements are actually there or not. @Tusbar There this thing called SO Snippets, please use that. Its the document icon with the `<>` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length
```

Comment: Since he wants to know how many are checked this could even be improved to `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length`

Comment: **all checkboxes that are checked**

Comment: last statement from question is "How can I count all checkboxes?"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').length
```

For your city you can do following

```
$('input:checkbox.city:checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('input[type=checkbox].city:checked').length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.cbx').on('change', function () {
    alert($('input.cbx:checked').length);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ztrLjzav/1/)

Get the class that is similar to check box and get `length`